# Is the set W a subspace of R2. If so find a basis and dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra

W = { ( a, a+2b  ) in R2 | a,b in R2}

The set W is in a column formation like such:

```
   a
a + 2b
```

I concluded that W is a subspace of R2.

The zero vector is present.

It is closed under addition.

It is closed under scalar multiplication.

The dimension is 2 because the dimension of R2 is 2.

**I have no idea how to find a basis. How do i find one?**

Comment: If you believe that $W= \mathbb R^2$ then any basis of $\mathbb R^2$ is good.

Comment: Not every subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has dimension 2. So, you need some other argument.

Comment: Note that $(a,a+2b) = a\cdot (1,1)+b\cdot (0,2)$

Comment: @lulu Now your making me doubt myself... is W a subspace of R2 here?

Comment: @lanskey Dimension of R2 = n?

Comment: @JMoravitz I am confused by what that means.

Comment: @Aeryes What is your definition of dimension of a vector space?

Comment: Every vector of the form $(a,a+2b)$ can be written as a linear combination of $(1,1)$ and $(0,2)$...  Now... look at the definition of a basis and look at the definition of dimension.

Comment: @Aeryes  Your argument is right, but you can write it more simply.  Just show that you can write every element in $\mathbb R^2$ can be written as $(a,a+2b)$  for suitable, $a,b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W=\{(a,a+2b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. Note that for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
(a,a+2b)=(a,a)+(0,2b)=a(1,1)+b(0,2).
$$
From this it is immediately evident that $W$ is the span of the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(0,2)$. So, it is a vector space. If we showed that these two vectors are linearly independent then they are a basis. Do you know how to show that two vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: We write up the matrix and row reduce. It needs to have only the trivial solution to be independent.

Comment: @Aeyes yes, this is one way to do this. In this case it is (even) easier to find the determinant of the matrix composed of these vectors. If the determinant is not 0, then the vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: And the dimension in this case is n, which is 2.

Comment: @Aeryes it is unclear what is $n$. The dimension of $W$ is 2 because its basis consists of 2 vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have really helped clear this up for me :)

Comment: @Aeryes You are welcome!